# No Guideline / Documentation for Jenkins default certificate expiration

Tags: jenkins, certificate, adfs, jks

My `jenkins.cer` and `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` certificate under `JENKINS_HOME` has expired causing integration with ADFS using SAML 2.0 to fail.

I did not find any documentation on how to update the certificate or keystore.

Infact, I do not even know the password to `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` for making changes (updating the certificates) to the `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` file.

Can you please help direct me as to what needs to be done inorder to get the `jenkins.cer` and `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` renewed.

I tried deleting both `jenkins.cer` and `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` and restarting Jenkins expecting it to recreate both the files afresh.

However, a restart does not create `jenkins.cer` and `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` file.

I need  to change the validity of `jenkins.cer` and `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks` for the ADFS integration to work.

I would also be interested in knowing the trust store password for `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks`

The expiration of Jenkins certificate causes integration between `Jenkins` and `ADFS` to break.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific document for Jenkins default certificate expiration. Kindly try the below steps and check if it resolves your issue.

You need to remove certificates from JENKINS_HOME and restart jenkins service. Jenkins will generate new certificates.  Remove the file from JENKINS_HOME: saml-jenkins-keystore.jks saml-jenkins-keystore.xml jenkins.cer and Restart Jenkins.

Try to get access Jenkins through web interface and it will generate a new saml-jenkins-keystore.jks saml-jenkins-keystore.xml

Generate jenkins.cer using the new jks keytool -export -alias saml-generated-keypair -keystore saml-jenkins-keystore.jks -rfc -file jenkins.cer.

Kindly let me know if you have any queries

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, renewing certificates in Jenkins requires a restart. I say this, because on Linux, the JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE config parameter is part of the *systemd* config (e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system`) as opposed to the Jenkins config (e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins`). Jenkins won't even start without getting the certificate configuration correct, implying that it must be restarted when that configuration is changed.

Hence the process of renewing certificates in Jenkins is two-fold:

1. Create the new certificate (.jks file) using `keytool` or the like.
2. Restart Jenkins with `sudo systemctl restart jenkins`

Note: If you change the location of your SSL certificate, you need to update the  jenkins service config at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` and then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` before restarting.